backup databases SQL Always On
I have SQL Server 2022 with Always On Availability Group on two Servers.
SRVSQL01 - Primary Replica
SRVSQL02 - Secondary Replica
On SRVSQL01, the Full backup is performed normally. When SRVSQL01 becomes a Secondary replica, the following error message appears.
"This BACKUP or RESTORE command is not supported on a database mirror or secondary replica."
What should I do so that the database backup continues to run even when Failover occurs?
Thank you.

Assuming you are doing the backup as part of a SQL Agent job, then create a new step in the job that runs before the backup step, that runs this code:
-- Check whether we're running on the Primary/Active node.
-- If it isn't, raise a message so we skip the next step(s)
IF NOT ((SELECT ars.role_desc
     FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
    INNER JOIN sys.availability_groups ag ON ars.group_id = ag.group_id
    WHERE ag.name = '<<Your_Availability_Group_Name>>'
      AND ars.is_local = 1) = 'PRIMARY' 
    OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.availability_groups) = 0)
BEGIN
  -- Running on the secondary node.  Raise an error so we skip the next step
  RAISERROR('Running on Secondary node. Electing to NOT run the job because it should be running on the Primary/Active node.', 11, 1)
END

Make sure in the Advanced tab to change the On Failure Action to Quit the job reporting success, as this is the behaviour you want to occur.
EDIT: Note the alternative answer by Ivan that uses sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(@DBNAME), which is probably a better option for backup jobs as it takes into account the backup preference specified.  The code I used is applicable in other use cases though.
Alternatively, look into the Ola Hallengren maintenance solution, which has this baked in and is very widely used.
P.S. You probably want identical jobs setting up on the Secondary server also, so that your backups continue to be taken after failover.  This is especially so with LOG backups, otherwise your log file will start filling up.

Thank you @paulH, you helped me a lot.

There is a separate article in the Microsoft documentation dedicated to configuring backup on the secondary replica.
In short, you first need to specify in the AG settings where you prefer to make a backup:

After that, you can use the function sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(@DBNAME) within a specific instance - to understand whether you need to make a backup here.
IF (sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica(@DBNAME) != 1)
BEGIN

    Select 'This is not the preferred replica, exiting with success';
    RETURN 0 -- This is a normal, expected condition, so the script return success

END

BACKUP DATABASE @DBNAME TO DISK = '<path to backup file>'
WITH COPY_ONLY;


